# zipping large files on a web server causing massive slow down

Tags: asp.net

We have a standard ASP.NET based web page where you can download multiple uploaded files by clicking a "Download All Files" Button.
When you do this we zip up all the files on the server and then you know download it.   The experience is very similar to skydrive etc.
Here is the thing if one of the files , to be zipped, is large ( over a gig ) then the CPU utilization on the server spikes like insanely high. Have three , four client try and the same time and the web server just becomes unresponsive in general.

A few things, for fun I tried just zipping a file on my local box ( file was over a gig in size) . My machine just crawled CPU util was like 80%.

So what is the solution , every one and their younger brother allows you to download zipped files form the web, what are we doing wrong, is there some standard clever way of zipping files on the server without causing massive slowdown.

Comment: Which component are you using for zipping?

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid the slowdown for the other users, you could limit the number of zip runs that are done in parallel, e.g. by using a Semaphore. See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx) for a sample.

Downside is that the zipping runs are delayed if there are several parallel runs - but at least the server should stay responsive for the other users.

If you can predict the packages that users want to download, you can also prepare by zipping the files before and retrieve the zipped files without zipping them on the fly. This also works if you can cache the zipped files, so that the zipping process is only done for the first user who wants to have a new combination. Of course, you'd need to track changes of the files so that you can invalidate the cached zip files.